# Example with Roxygen for R Package

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm trying to add an example of a function within my package. That for I want to use roxygen2. I'm doing the following
(just a part of my code, at the end of roxygen2 documentation and until the code of the function starts
   ...

```
#' @import  EcoHydRology
#' @export
#' @example
#' Tx <- 29
#' Tn <- 13
#' rain <- 100
#' lat <- 1
#' Ion <- 10
#' DOY <- 44
#' z <- 450
#' c <- 2.4
#' B <- 0.004
#'
#' BC_alt(Tx, Tn, rain, lat, lon, DOY, z, c, B)



BC_alt <- function(Tx, Tn, rain, lat, lon, DOY, z, c, B){



  #Extraterrestrial solar radiation (with EcoHydRology package)
  lat_rad <- lat*pi/180

  A <- 0.75+(2*10^(-5)*z)
```

...
So when I than try to Build & Reload, I get an error message

```
>     Fehler in file(con, "r") : kann Verbindung nicht öffnen
>     Ruft auf: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... process_examples -> unlist -> lapply -> FUN -> file
>     Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
>     In file(con, "r") :
>       kann Datei '/Users/Manuelito/Dropbox/CIAT/SolariradianceBC/SolariradianceBC/Tx <-
> 29
>     Tn <- 13
>     rain <- 100
>     lat <- 1
>     Ion <- 10
>     DOY <- 44
>     z <- 450
>     c <- 2.4
>     B <- 0.004
>     
>     BC_alt(Tx, Tn, rain, lat, lon, DOY, z, c, B)' nicht öffnen: No such file or directory
```

sorry it is partly in german. Principally it says it can't find such a file.

But I don't get how I have to do it that it works. 
Do I have to create a new script for the function so the @example command can find it? 
I think something is wired with the file path 
the script of my function is called BristowCampbell.R and its file path is
/Users/Manuelito/Dropbox/CIAT/SolariradianceBC/SolariradianceBC/R/BrisowCampbell.R 
so that's maybe the reason why it can't find it. But anyway in the error message its saying it can't find the file but i'm only calling a function in a script. I think I kind didn't understand how to use @example from roxygen2. I would be vary glad, if anybody could give me a hint. 
Thank you very much
Manuel

Comment: Two questions: (1) Does the function `BC_alt`, as defined in your package, at _any_ point try to reference, load, read or do anything with a hard coded full file path? If so, that is probably wrong and needs to be changed. (2) Have you tried wrapping the example in `dontrun{}`? (this will likely just be a band-aid).

Comment: I would use the devtools::document() function. Essentially, it'll create .Rd files to the man directory and adds a NAMESPACEfile to the main directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@examples`, not `@example` (it's meant for code stored in external files)